# Compute distribution for count distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

In Poisson point processes, we first let $N$ be a random Poisson random variable, with parameter $\lambda$: 
$$
P(N=n)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot\lambda^n}{n!},\qquad n=0,1,\ldots
$$
Without loss of generality, we let $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n,\dots)$ be an i.i.d. sequence (infinite) of standard normal random variables. In addition, assume $N$ is independent of $Y$.
$$
f_{Y_i}(y_i)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y_i^2}{2}},\qquad -\infty<y_i<\infty
$$
Now we take an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$ and let $X$ be the number of $Y_i$s landing on the interval $[a,b]$, I want to know what is the distribution of $X$ here, I know it is a little bit complicated...

I searched Wikipedia and read the section [on the uniformity of the points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Points_are_uniformly_distributed), but I still not getting it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing things here because this has nothing to do with the distribution of points of the Poisson Process. Fix $N$ for a moment. Then the number of $Y_i$'s that fall within $[a,b]$ is binomially distributed: define $p:=p({[a,b]})=P(Y_1\in [a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$, where $F$ is the CDF of the standard normal. Then $X$ is binomially distributed (conditional on $N$ fixed): $P(X|N)=\binom{N}{X}p^X(1-p)^{N-X}$.

You're interested in $N$ being Poisson distributed. Since you're allowed $N=0$ with positive probability, lets define $P(X=0|N=0)=1$. Above we calculated the conditional distribution of $X$ so:

$$P(X)=\sum_{N=0}^\infty P(X|N)P(N),$$

which looks like it can be expressed in terms of generalized gamma functions [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%20Binomial%5BN,x%5D*(p%5Ex)*(1-p)%5E(1-x)*L%5EN%2FFactorial%5BN%5D,%7BN,1,Infinity%7D%5D).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It is really a nice point that we define p as the probability that $Y_i$ is in [a,b] so $p = F(b)-F(a)$ But I still wonder whether the binomial result is the probability mass function, or the conditional distribution..... Again thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. $X$ is binomially distributed, conditional on the value of $N$.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking the wrong question...... X|N should be binomially distributed but ..... X itself should incorporate the poisson process, to get the poisson distribution.~~ You help~

Comment: If you do the algebra correctly, you will see that the unconditional distribution of X is also Poisson, with a parameter λp = λ[F(b)-F(a)]